# Creating multiple bundles using angular-cli webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-cli

When i build the project using angular-cli, it bundles all project files into one big main bundle.

I have used lazy routing in the application and i can navigate fine once application loads up.

Is there a way in which main bundle is divided into multiple files based upon lazy loaded routes modules?

below is the configuration in `angular-cli.json`

```
    {
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "name": "maddy-test-project"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "styles/content",
      "index": "default.htm",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.less"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "styles/wfa-myriad-pro-typekit.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "less",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

below is package.json

```
{
  "name": "maddy-test-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "d3": "^4.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",  
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.35",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.1.27",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/jquery": "^1.10.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.34",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.29",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the role of **NgModule** and **RouterModule.forChild()**. Here is a very good article for starting big Angular 2 modular aplications developpement : http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/

> The first thing that we need to do is to remove every mention of the Home component or the HomeModule from the App component and the main routing configuration:
>
> We can see here that the App component no longer imports HomeModule, instead the routing config uses loadChildren to say that if /home or any other url starting with it gets hit, then the file home.module should be loaded via an Ajax call.

Shortly, to move some logic and components in a lazy module, you can run this command :

```
ng g module child --routing
```

Then angular-cli will generate a NgModule (`app/child/child.module.ts`) and a child router configuration (`app/child/child-routing.module.ts`).

The route for lazy loading this child router will be :

```
 { path: 'child', loadChildren: 'app/child/child.module#ChildModule' }
```

And finally move what you want in your ChildModule with one constraint : other module (as AppModule) will not be able to use any ChildModule dependency (like a service, for example). If you need it, a good practice is to create a shared module.

Comment: `ng g module child` will no longer generate the component since beta.24 (beta.23 not published). We need to use `ng g module child --routing`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1 more thing I need to know, how do you know that "ng g module child will no longer generate the component since beta.24"? Is there any documentation where from I also get those kind of important release information of angular-cli?

Comment: Component generation is optional with module generation. This is a feature (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3389) with beta 23 (that wasn't published as @Timathon said) : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta23-2016-12-15. With beta 24, the component is generated by default.

Answer (score 4):

If your splitting the areas that you want to be lazy loaded into separate modules, you should be able to produce multiple bundles. Take a look at this  [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZsDR12BGjvjOMwG22RXX?p=preview) on routing and navigation taken directly from the angular.io website.
If you configure your routes this way you should be able to produce a build when running ng serve similar to:
[image]
Notice the chunk files. In my project, these chunk files get loaded asynchronously when navigating to the 'crisis' and 'heroes' routes.

```javascript
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' },
  { path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
];
```

Comment: how do I do chunking with webpack